# Delete last n Column(s) of DataTable dt

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

I am copying DataTable dt from DataTable dtOld, so When I copied the DataTable I got some extra colmns please advise how to retain n number(s) of column and delete rest of columns.

my code:

```
private DataTable GetdtfromdtOld()
{
    DataTable dt = dtOld.Copy();

    dt.Columns["Column1"].SetOrdinal(0);
    dt.Columns["Column2"].SetOrdinal(1);

    dt.Columns["Column3"].SetOrdinal(2);
    dt.Columns["Column4"].SetOrdinal(3);

    dt.Columns["Column4"].SetOrdinal(4);
    dt.Columns["Column5"].SetOrdinal(5);
    dt.Columns["Column6"].SetOrdinal(6);

    dt.Columns["Column7"].SetOrdinal(7);
    dt.Columns["Column8"].SetOrdinal(8);

    dt.Columns["Column9"].SetOrdinal(9);
    dt.Columns["Column10"].SetOrdinal(10);

    dt.AcceptChanges();

    //Remove the Extra Column of dt
    for (int dtCol = dt.Columns.Count - 1; dt > 10; dtCol--)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(dtCol);
        //Get the last Column
        //Column10 is name of last col in my code which has to be return 
        if (dt.Columns[dtCol].ColumnName != "Column10")
        {
            dt.Columns.RemoveAt(dtCol);
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    return dt;
}
```

Comment: whats wrong with that

Comment: Well, if `ExceptedLastColName` is the last column you will exit the loop immediately

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding @TimSchmelter, the 'ExceptedLastColName' is what I want to retain as my last col in DataTable 'dt', and it is 'Column10'. BTW, I have solved my code and successfully achieved expected col in my DataTable 'dt'. and edited the Question as per my code. Can any suggest me how to close the question as I have solved it myself.

Comment: @AnkitKumarPatel:post an answer and accept that. What was wrong with [my approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49982640/284240)?

Comment: Hi @Tim, Even my approach was not bad, It was working... so does this edited one. also in your approach you code shows that if code get the 'ExceptedLastColName' it will skip that column because 'continue' keyword. Please check and revert. thx

Comment: @AnkitKumarPatel: well, if there is no issue you don't need this question. You have solved it yourself

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your backwards-loop is that you exit it as soon as `ExceptedLastColName` is found and you comment that this is actually the last column. So you will exit the loop immediately.

Try this:

```
for (int dtCol = dt.Columns.Count - 1; dt > 10; dtCol--)
{
    //ExceptedLastColName is name of last col in my code
    if (dt.Columns[dtCol].ColumnName == "ExceptedLastColName")
    {
        continue;
    }
    else
    {
        dt.Columns.RemoveAt(dtCol);
    }
}
```